# Add Quantity Selected to Cart Instead of Just Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have an index page with items and a quantity select form.

[image]

The form works for create (a.k.a. first click).  The problem is, if I click it again, it's just updating the cart instead of adding that quantity to the `line_item`.  If this was my only problem I would be able to solve it myself.

The real problem is that I have another form that updates right before checkout.  It looks like this:

[image]

I want this to be the master quantity control, so whatever goes in that form is what the quantity will be for update. But for the first images, I want that quantity to add to the quantity of the `@line_item`, so I can't just make a method that just adds the new and old quantities together, which is what I started doing until I realized I wouldn't be able to do that.

Do I need to make a new action in the controller?
What would be the work around for this?

Comment: you don't want to update your cart on second click? and why is it updating it when your path takes it to the create method?

Comment: its a form for @line_item so it creates it if it doesn't exist and updates it if it does... I think.  What do you mean by "you don't want to update your cart on second click?"

Comment: i mean you want to create a new item instead of updating the previous one?

Comment: i think i got it now, lets say you have an item A in cart and then you again click on add to cart then it's creating another item A in your cart instead of just updating the quantity of already existed item A, right?

Comment: That could be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question

`The problem is, if I click it again, it's just updating the cart instead of adding that quantity to the line_item`

The problem is your *submit button* `Add to Cart` which takes it to the **create action of your cart** and hence *creating a new item inside your cart*

`Do I need to make a new action in the controller?`

My answer would be yes. You need to make a *new action with post route request(to find that item)* and then update its quantity inside that action.

`What would be the work around for this?`

If you look at your button or rather i should say **form** for creating a new item then it's the **path or url part** in your form which takes it to your method inside your controller. If you change its url then it will take it to your custom method.

**Fix**

All you need is some js magic to dynamically change the url or your form after a user has clicked on your Add to Cart button. Something like:

```
$(document).on("click","your_button_class",function(){
  $(this).closest("your_form_class").attr("action","path_of_new_method");
});
```

You will also have to supply your **items id by this form** by adding a hidden field or something and then find that item inside controller method with that id to update its quantity.

**Note:** You need to call this js after your form is submitted and a new item is already created else it can trouble you.